# Oversip in front of Opensips

Tags: sip, opensips

Salam,

I want to set Oversip as a SIP Proxy, to handle TCP, TLS and WSS connections, and relay all traffic to Opensips SIP Server, converting all connections to UDP only . My questions are:

1. is it a good design to do so?
2. Opensips is not able to get the location of the , so I'm not able to route messages back, Opensips -> Oversip -> Client. any help or tutorial (I googled it and can't find any)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is bad design, becuase opensips already can do TCP and TLS.

But you you insist you need that, you can add sip header with needed info when callign opensips/read it on opensips.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I went through a thread that says opensips  is not designed to handle TCP connections at first place as it doesn't use asynchronous reactors (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.voip.opensips.user/27141). Anyway, what kind of header should I add, I really appreciate if you can clarify more.

Comment: http://www.cs.rice.edu/CS/Architecture/docs/ram-ispass08.pdf  openser&opensips&kamailio is same architecture. I am afraid you have learn sip protocol first. WIthout that you can't configure opensips